# plugged 240v into 110v amplifer - is this repairable?

Tags: voltage, amplifier

I imported a 200w mono subwoofer amplifer from the US and stupidly misread the 250v fuse rating as the input voltage. Plugged it in into my UK 240v supply and the slow-blow fuse blew. I have since replaced this, but the unit does not power on.

If I replace the power supply board with a 240v one (or repair the 110v board and use an inverter), is it still likely that the amplifier circuit has been destroyed in the process?

Comment: It helps if you tell us which subwoofer you did this to. If all circuits were the same, electrical engineers would be out of a job..

Comment: Pearl Throne Thumper (by Buttkicker) http://pearldrum.com/products/kits/electronic-drumsets/throne-thumper/

Comment: Of course it's repairable. But it will probably cost more than simply replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it had a proper power supply (almost everything does nowadays), that would have isolated the amp itself from the mains so any damage is probably only in the power supply, most 110V switching power supplies use a voltage doubler to get something like 300-400VDC from 110AC, hooking up 240 probably generated a high enough voltage to cook the input rectifier and the switching transistors, the rest of the supply *might* be ok as the control electronics tends to run from a small low voltage AUX supply. This is of course assuming it used a switching supply, a good ol' fashioned mains transformer/linear regulator may have resulted in a blown pass transistor and possibly the output transistors